# How to strip out width and height attributes on hard-coded image from database

Tags: php, database

The following code comes in from the database and the `mw` and `mh` values are messing everything up. How can I strip those out?

Here is my code:

```
<a class="wgt_ListingsSpread_thumblink" href="/listings/1193975-19-xxxx--whitby-ontario">
<img border="0" src="http://media.realwebleads.com/mlsphoto.php?mls=toronto&lid=1193975&pic=0&mw=160&mh=138">
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to see the PHP code, not the HTML it's generating.

Comment: If I remove those values, [I get nothing at all](http://media.realwebleads.com/mlsphoto.php?mls=toronto&lid=1193975&pic=0&mw=&mh=). Apparently *some* value for those variables is required, and you just want to change them... but to what?

Comment: Dude, not enough info...

Comment: In any case, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is probably what you'll want to use.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this function to remove parameters from a give URL:

```
function removeParamter($url, $varname) {
    list($urlpart, $qspart) = array_pad(explode('?', $url), 2, '');
    parse_str($qspart, $qsvars);
    @unset($qsvars[$varname]);
    $newqs = http_build_query($qsvars);
    return $urlpart . '?' . $newqs;
}
```

In your case you would need to call it twice to remove the 2 paramters `mw` and `mh`:

```
$url = 'http://media.realwebleads.com/mlsphoto.php?mls=toronto&lid=1193975&pic=0&mw=160&mh=138'

$url = removeParamter($url, 'mw');
$url = removeParamter($url, 'mh');

//wanted URL
echo $url;
```